# Mapping definition has unsupported parameters: [store : true]

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I defined my index `ads` as follows:

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
         default: { host: %elastica_host%, port: %elastica_port% }         
    indexes:
          ads:
            types:                        
                brand:
                    mappings:
                        name:
                            type: string
                            boost: 5
                        slug:
                            type: string
                            boost: 4
                        date : ~
                        isPublished: ~
                        user:
                            type: nested
                            properties: 
                                username: ~
                                email: ~
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: Minn\AdsBundle\Entity\Brend
                        elastica_to_model_transformer:
                            service: minn_ads.transformers_elastica.brand
                        provider: ~
                        listener:
                            immediate: ~
                        finder: ~
```

**FYI:** 1. This is how `Brend` is linked with `User` with @ManyToOne

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Minn\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $user;
```

**FYI:** 2. I am using the `dev-master` branches for  FOSElasticaBundle and Elastica. For elasticsearch, I am using 2.1.1.

A populate command `php app/console fos:elastica:populate` always returns this error:

**[Elastica\Exception\ResponseException]

  {"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Mapping definition for [user] has unsupported parameters:  [store : true]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [brand]:

   Mapping definition for [user] has unsupported parameters:  [store : true]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Mapping definition for [user] has unsupported parameters:  [store : true]"}}**

I checked the `app/logs/dev.log`, I found that the generated mapping for the index `ads` has an extra parameter `"store":true`. You can check that down:

**[2015-12-20 21:28:21] elastica.DEBUG: logging Request {"path":"ads/","method":"PUT","data":{"mappings":{"brand":{"properties":{"name":{"type":"string","boost":5,"store":true},"slug":{"type":"string","boost":4,"store":true},"date":{"type":"string","store":true},"isPublished":{"type":"string","store":true},"user":{"type":"nested","properties":{"username":{"type":"string","store":true},"email":{"type":"string","store":true}},"store":true}},"dynamic_date_formats":[],"_meta":{"model":"Minn\AdsBundle\Entity\Brend"}}}},"query":[],"connection":{"config":{"headers":[]},"host":"127.0.0.1","port":9200,"logger":"fos_elastica.logger","enabled":true}} []**

Below is the mapping with the extra `"store": true`. Is there any idea on how to configure FOSElasticaBundle to get a mapping without this extra line with `"store": true` ?

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "brand": {
            "properties": {
                "name": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "boost": 5,
                    "store": true
                },
                "slug": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "boost": 4,
                    "store": true
                },
                "date": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": true
                },
                "isPublished": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "store": true
                },
                "user": {
                    "type": "nested",
                    "properties": {
                        "username": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "store": true
                        },
                        "email": {
                            "type": "string",
                            "store": true
                        }
                    },
                    "store": true  # extra line! If deleted, it will work!
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For those willing to follow, [an issue has been opened](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/issues/985) in the FOSElasticaBundle Github repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a bug in `MappingBuilder.php` which tries to add `store: true` whenever the [`store` property is not specified](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/197e90539977b1ae8fd6f4d31bb05940bd217829/Index/MappingBuilder.php#L129).

What you could try is to explicitly specify `store: false` so that the `!isset($property['store'])` test fails:

```
                mappings:
                    name:
                        type: string
                        boost: 5
                    slug:
                        type: string
                        boost: 4
                    date : ~
                    isPublished: ~
                    user:
                        type: nested
                        store: false        <---
                        properties: 
                            username: ~
                            email: ~
```

Another thing you could try is to modify the private [`$skipTypes`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/197e90539977b1ae8fd6f4d31bb05940bd217829/Index/MappingBuilder.php#L24) array to include `nested` in addition of `completion`, that could do the trick.

Comment: store: false did not work! I just commented the code making this bug. There is PR on that!

Comment: That's what I feared. What about `$skipTypes`?

Comment: I have not understood you solution regarding `$skipTypes`... Can update you answer?

Comment: In `MappingBuilder.php` (line 24) you could try to add `nested` to the `$skipTypes` array, i.e. `private $skipTypes = array('completion','nested');`

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the FOSElasticaBundle. It is solved in this [PR 987](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/pull/987).

You have just to comment the lines in [Index/MappingBuilder.php](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSElasticaBundle/blob/197e90539977b1ae8fd6f4d31bb05940bd217829/Index/MappingBuilder.php#L129) related to that bug!